# How do I stop Word 2013 from removing the page break that I enter between the Table of Contents and the body when I update all references?

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

When I update all references in my document (by pressing Ctrl + A, then pressing F9), Microsoft Word 2013 removes the page break that I had entered after the Table of Contents.

Sometimes it does this, sometimes it doesn't. I can't identify the reason.